# Do I have to open source my project if I use a piece of code licensed under GPL as a part of my project?

Tags: open-source, licensing

If there is a javascript library that is licensed under a Copyleft license like the GPL, what must I do to use it?  Would I have to make my whole website open source just because I used that javascript library?

Comment: Read the license, this isn't a programming question - http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.txt

Comment: @Mimisbrunnr I browsed over the license and still was confused.  And there are 500+ questions tagged licensing, so I figure its an okay topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: And some of us are constantly trying to close them all :-)

Comment: true, sorry. I've read it over again, and posted what I think. @bmargulies - so true, so true.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a lawyer so take my advice with the <strike>grains</strike> kilotonne of salt it deserves. From the GPL:

> To "convey" a work means any kind of propagation that enables other
>   parties to make or receive copies.  Mere interaction with a user through
>   a computer network, with no transfer of a copy, is not conveying.
>
> ...
>
> You may make, run and propagate covered works that you do not
>   convey, without conditions so long as your license otherwise remains
>   in force.

So I would take this to mean, no, only the used library has to stay under the GPL as per the license. The license stipulates it must be displayed and unchanged, that is all.

Comment: Thanks for the edit paxdiablo

Comment: There probably is a *significant* difference in how the "convey" language applies to server-side vs client-side script.  When I see "JavaScript", I think client-side, and a copy IS transferred.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that this is still a matter of debate. The stance taken by the Free Software Foundation, which holds all of the GPL copyrights and enforces them, is that any code that links with GPL code, whether statically or dynamically, must also be under the GPL. So in this case, yes you would have to open source your project - but only if you were to distribute it at all. Nothing is forcing you to distribute your code.

So I would agree that you're ok with using it. Personally, I wouldn't use any GPL code in a website that sells anything as part of a for-profit company, even though it's probably legal too (it's likely considered the "output" of the code). The realm of free software licenses in regards to web code is still not completely clear, so I try to follow the spirit of the rules when I can.